Change contours into straight lines
Image
I have a problem with detected contours. The contours are as in the attached photo. I would like to remove all the inscriptions from them (connect the broken lines in these places) and align their course so that they are as close to straight lines as possible.
I tried to detect the contours using different methods. Currently my code looks like this:
def detect_wires(image_path, lower_color, upper_color):
    img = cv2.imread(image_path)
    img_hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
    mask = cv2.inRange(img_hsv, np.array(lower_color), np.array(upper_color))
    contours, _ = cv2.findContours(mask, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

    return contours

Are there any easy ways to do this?

How did you detect this contours? Please post the code you have that detects the contours, and your attempts at merging them into straight lines. We need to know in what format are this contours saved.

take a look at https://answers.opencv.org/question/231691/merge-contour-from-vectorpoints/  You can then apply Hough Lines to try to detect the lines those contours form.
